# Natural Deduction: Universal Quantifiers in Predicate

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

How do we prove the conclusion: ∀x(Ax ∨ ⇁Ax)

This is also called LEM, i.e. the Law of Excluded Middle.
I'm confused while proving this because for ∀x, deduction assuming some constant is required.
So, using universal quantifier Introduction and Elimination rules, how can the conclusion be reached?

Comment: Usually, LEM is not an axiom of ND; if so, you have to prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prove $(Aa \lor \neg Aa)$ from no premisses.

Then universally generalize. Which you can since $a$ appears in no live assumption.

Comment: So, after we assume constant a, how do we take Aa. There are no premises, so do we take Aa randomly?

Comment: My intro logic text is freely downloadable from https://www.logicmatters.net/ifl. Look at the proof of propositional excluded  middle on p. 212. Use $Aa$ instead of $P$!  And you get a proof of $(Aa \lor \neg Aa)$.

Comment: OMG! The book's super helpful and contains exactly the same type of problems I was practicing for my Logic classes! Mind Blowing 

Comment: You're welcome. There are worked answers to (most) exercises online too which you might find helpful. Spread the word to your classmates ;)